# How to get Javascript array to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am building a asp.net application where users can order food, and i also have a admin page where the admins can login and make a menu for a specific week.
I have solved everything inside that "Menu maker" and when i press the Save button every value from the menu goes into a javascript array.

So to the problem. When i press the save button I want to serialize the array to json to then be able to pass it over to my mvc controller.

I am trying to do that with ajax. This is the full code of the save button click:

```
$("#CreateMenuBtn").on('click', function () {
FullMenu.push(
    {
        "Year": $("#YearInput").val(),
        "Week": $("#WeekInput").val(),
        "Products": MenuArray
    }
);
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify({ methodParam: FullMenu });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: dataToPost,
    traditional: true
});
console.log(FullMenu);
});
```

When i now debugg and check the value of `data` it is perfectly right and in JSON format:

```
methodParam
 [0]
   Year: "2019"
   Week: "4"
   Products:
   [0]
      WeekDay: "Måndag"
      Food: "kött"
      Price: "54kr"
      Cabinet: "C"
   [1]
      Weekday: "Onsdag"
      Food: "Köttbullar"
      Price: "80kr"
      Cabinet: "B"
```

Now I want it to my mvc controller.

I have a classes called `Menu` and `Product` it looks like this:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string Week { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }

}



public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public char Cabinet { get; set; }

    public int MenuID { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

This is what i came up with in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index(List<Menu> methodParam)
    {
       foreach(Menu item in methodParam)
        {
            string des = item.Week + item.Year;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

But when i debugging inside the action inside the foreach loop, `methodParam` gets the value 0.

So what i want help with is how I can get the array into c#.
I hope that explains my situation, would appreciate som help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you `stringify` your data, then you are only passing a single property/argument of type `string` to your controller.  You can accept that string in the controller and deserialise it in the C# or you can send it as actual data and let the binding do it for you.

Comment: The variable `dataToPost` contains a stringifyed array, how do you mead I should doafter that, can you give a little example, it may just be me who is dumb right now but I did not undertand how to do it @freedomn-m

Comment: @luddep Try with `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Comment: Still the same output `methodParam Count = 0` @jom

Comment: Change the `contentType` as above *and* remove the stringify: `$.ajax({ .., data: { methodParam: FullMenu }, ...`

Comment: *or* change your MVC action signature to: `public IActionResult Index(string jsonData)` (may also need to change your `$.ajax` to `$.ajax({.. data: { jsonData: dataToPost }, ..` - I never use stringify with MVC so not 100% sure).

Comment: @luddep Also, you might want to use `@Html.BeginForm` so jQuery can [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the fields for you, rather than you having to do this manually.

Comment: @jom Where should I put `@Html.BeginForm`

Comment: @freedomn-m How would ithen be able to get the array to the classes `Menu` and `Product` ? By the way, thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: You would configure your js object so that it has the same properties as your MVC model is expecting, which it looks like it does, so should be handled for you by the model binder.  Or do you mean if you use `string jsonData`?  In that case you add code at the top of your action to deserialise to your `List<Menu>`

Comment: @luddep Please show us this View that renders the menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem :D 
Changed the url to `/Home(Controller name)/Index(Action name)`

```
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/Create',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: dataToPost,
    traditional: true
});
```

And the action needed to have `[FromBody]` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> jsonMenu)
{
    //Code
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Thanks a lot to you guys who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 var FullMenu = [];
        var Menu1 = {};
        Menu1['Year'] = "2016",
            Menu1['Week'] = "Jan";
        FullMenu.push(Menu1);
        var Menu2 = {};
        Menu2['Year'] = "2017",
            Menu2['Week'] = "Feb";
        FullMenu.push(Menu2);
        var dataToPost = FullMenu;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                methodParam: dataToPost
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all try to make c# classes structure same as json object same properties names 
then try

```
public IActionResult Index(string methodParam)
    {
       List<Menu> menu = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Menu>(methodParam);
       foreach(Menu item in menu)
        {
            string des = item.Week + item.Year;
        }
        return View();
    }
```